# as2 homing missile error on full rotation

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

In my current project I have some homing code (not exclusive to missiles) and I'm encountering some errors in the calculations when the missile is pointing straight up it starts to freak out and often turns in the wrong direction. Most of the time it works but after a full rotation it seems to break.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your rotation is becoming either negative or greater than 360. This can cause some problems with certain calculations such as if you're doing a check for if the rotation is greater than or less than 180, a full rotation would then make it always greater than 180.

Try adding something like this to your code:

```
R=Self._rotation;
if(R<0){R+=360;}
if(R>360){R=R%360;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is probably what is happening.